# Add multiple textures to a one-texture block

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

How do I add multiple textures (Like top, bottom, side, etc.) to a block with only one texture (Such as planks, dirt, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assigning Textures

In your `blocks.json` in the top of the directory (i.e. `myresourcepack/blocks.json`) have the block texture defined with these. Example `blocks.json` with a furnace:

```
{
  "furnace" : {
      "sound" : "stone",
      "textures" : {
         "down" : "furnace_top",
         "east" : "furnace_side",
         "north" : "furnace_side",
         "south" : "furnace_front_off",
         "up" : "furnace_top",
         "west" : "furnace_side"
      }
   }
}
```

- `furnace` - ID of block
- `furnace_top`, `furnace_side`... - Name you registered the texture under
- `stone` - The sound. Name the sound is registered under (optional)

## Registering Textures

The different sides should point to a registered texture. If you don't know how to register textures, here is an example:

Have a file named `terrain_texture.json`. The file path should be: `myresourcepack/textures/terrain_texture.json`. Inside the file, have this:

```
{
   "num_mip_levels" : 4,
   "padding" : 8,
   "resource_pack_name" : "vanilla",
   "texture_data" : {
      "acacia_planks" : {
         "textures" : "textures/blocks/planks_acacia"
      }
   }
}
```

In that example, we defined a texture called `acacia_planks` with the file path to the actual image `textures/blocks/planks_acacia`. This points to the `planks_acacia` file in our `myresourcepack/textures/blocks/planks_acacia.png`; the `.png` is implied.

- `acacia_planks` - Whatever you want to name the texture
- `planks_acacia` - The name of the PNG file in `blocks/`, omit the `.png`
- As for the mip, padding, pack name, etc. I couldn't tell you what anything does - just copy & paste that in

Comment: So, for example, if I wanted to add a different top to a dirt block, I would just edit `blocks.json`?

Comment: No, you would have to register the new texture in terrain_texture.json  then make a blocks.json for it

Comment: Can you link to an example pack answering the question "Add multiple textures to a one-texture block?"